# How do I put a correct spacing/format when printing java 2d array multiplication table

Tags: java, arrays

Title speaks for itself....
I want to correct the print format when printing the java 2d array multiplication table.

Instead of printing like this:

```
   1   2   3   4   5
   2   4   6   8  10
   3   6   9  12  15
   4   8  12  16  20
   5  10  15  20  25
```

It should print like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5
2   4   6   8   10
3   6   9   12  15
4   8   12  16  20
5   10  15  20  25
```

Here's my code:

`

```
int range = rowInput * colInput;

        int tableElem[][] = new int[range][range];

        for (int row = 0; row < rowInput; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < colInput; col++) {
                tableElem [row] [col] = (row+1) * (col+1);
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < rowInput; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < colInput; col++) {
                System.out.printf("%4d",tableElem[row] [col]);
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
```

`

Comment: Seeing all the results are 1 or 2 digits, using a tab can work:  `System.out.print ("\t" + tableElem[row][col]);`

Comment: Off-topic: AFAIK, The _de facto_ standard and traditional way of printing columns of numbers is to have them right-justified, as in the first example. Most people I've worked with would say the first example is correct. This agrees with tables and other printed material I've seen.

Comment: ohhhhh THANK YOU SO MUCH Old Dog Programmer!!!!

Comment: Something I just learned:  Putting a `-` in the format specification causes left-justification:  `System.out.printf("%-4d",tableElem[row] [col]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rowInput; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < colInput; col++) {
            int res = tableElem[row] [col];
            System.out.print(tableElem[row] [col]);
             if(res>9){
                System.out.print(" ");  // 1 Space
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("  ");  // 2 Spaces
            }
        }
         System.out.print("\n");
    }
```